# Why Tomcat Context implements Pipeline interface and also contains a Pipeline field?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, web, containers

I am reading the book **"How Tomcat Works"**. In Chapter 5, the `SimpleContext` implements `Context` and `Pipeline` interface. But at the same time `SimpleContext` holds a Pipeline field (`SimplePipeline` implements `Pipeline` interface), and use `this` to construct it.

```
// Context implements Pipeline interface
public class SimpleContext implements Context, Pipeline { 
    public SimpleContext() {
      pipeline.setBasic(new SimpleContextValve());
    }
    protected HashMap children = new HashMap();
    protected Loader loader = null;

    // also contains a Pipeline field, and use "this" to construct it
    protected SimplePipeline pipeline = new SimplePipeline(this); 

    protected HashMap servletMappings = new HashMap();
    protected Mapper mapper = null;
    protected HashMap mappers = new HashMap();
    private Container parent = null;

    // remainder omitted ...
}
```

`SimplePipeline` also holds the reference of `Context` with which this Pipeline is associated.

```
public class SimplePipeline implements Pipeline {

  public SimplePipeline(Container container) {
    setContainer(container);
  }

  protected Valve basic = null;

  // The Container with which this Pipeline is associated.
  protected Container container = null;

  protected Valve valves[] = new Valve[0];

  // remainder omitted ...
}
```

If I was the author, I will either let `SimpleContext` implements `Pipeline` interface, or keep `Pipeline` as a member field of `Context`, not both of them.

I know that maybe author do this for some **"specific reason"**. Any one can tell me that reason?

Comment: [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern)

Comment: Thanks @ElliottFrisch ! Simple but useful tips,  I think I got the point!